# Adding a delay in a thread group - JMeter

Tags: jmeter, delay, delayed-execution

This may sound like a duplicate question but its nit, I've searched a lot before putting this here.

I have a single thread group with 10 users and 28 HTTP requests, what I want is something like:

```
Thread 1 --->rqst 1 
Thread 1 --->rqst 2 
Thread 1 --->rqst 3 
. 
. 
Thread 2 --->rqst 1 
Thread 2 --->rqst 2 
Thread 2 --->rqst 3 
. 
. 
Thread n --->rqst n
```

***delay one minute*** 
Start over again.

I tried using constant timer in the thread group but what i got was execution of a single request by all threads every time.

Can anyone please explain how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least 2 options:

1. Add [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) after all requests and configure it like:

   - Target: `All Threads`
   - Action: `Pause`
   - Duration: `60000`
2. Add Constant Timer **as a child** of `rqst 1`. Timers are executed **before** sampler so only one request will be impacted. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for more details on timers scope and detailed explanation of each and every Timer.

In both cases **delay won't be included into test results**

Comment: First option was what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a beanshell timer after the last request with something like this

```
if (${__threadNum} == 10){
    Integer WaitTime = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("WaitTime"));
    return WaitTime;
}
```

If the last thread has started add a sleep with milliseconds from the var WaitTime.

Or take a loop at the [jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/).